# How to filter Mantis issues that are not blocked

Tags: mantis

I am using Mantis BT to track my project's bugs and issues. Many issues can only be solved, after other issues have been solved before, so they are blocked by them.

Can I apply a filter that omits all issues that are dependent on not-solved other issues?